# GCP dataflow Workflow failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting an error repeatedly while running a job on Google Cloud Dataflow. I have been trying to create a job that counts words from a text file that is stored in a bucket. I simply chose a Dataflow template and filled in all the required information, such as the source, which is a GCP bucket, and the destination, which is the same bucket with a folder inside it. After filling in all the credentials, I started a job but received an error message that said:

> "Workflow failed. Causes: Permissions verification for controller service account failed. All permissions in IAM role roles/dataflow.worker should be granted to controller service account 671397198227-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com."
> The screenshot is provided as a proof.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzWqT.png)

The error message indicates that the permission role needs to be granted. I am the owner of this project and have all the permissions to perform any task. However, when I tried to change the permissions from owner to editor, it did not work. I need this job to run so that I can get a file in my bucket, which is the assigned destination. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your controller for this workflow uses a service account, which has it's own permissions. It does not share permissions with job creator.

To give the necessary permission for a service account you must go to **IAM & Admin > IAM > [Click on "Include Google-provided role grants"] > find the service account which you are using on your resource (in your case 671397198227-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) > Click on the pencil icon > + Add another role > Select the desired role (Dataflow Worker in this case) > Save.**

[image: IAM & Admin Panel]
[image: Mark Checkbox and Click on the Pencil icon]
[image: Dataflow Worker Role]

This should give you the necessary permissions to overcome this error. Keep in mind that depending what you job is doing you might get another permission denied kind error, then you must add the necessary role on the Service Account, while keeping this one.

Hope this helps you, let me know if you have any further questions!